# validate first 2 numbers of 5 digit number

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to validate a 5 digit number.

1. Max of 5 digits
2. First 2 digits are within various ranges like (00-16) or (20-25) or
   (32-39)
3. 00789 - valid
4. 11569 - valid
5. 22698 - valid
6. 32567 - valid
7. 17895 - not valid
8. 41578 - not valid

Is there a Regex Guru that can help with a regex expression that would work for this scenario?

I don't know anything about regular expressions. This a small part of a bigger solution that has legacy code using regular expression strings as data validation. A number comes in as a parameter. A lookup is done to get a regex validation string. The number and the regex string is passed to a validator where a regex.IsMatch is performed.

My question is can the above validation senario be written in a regex expression, if so what would that look like? I could then add the expression to the existing library of regex expressions in my app.

Comment: Why do you think this should be solved with regex?  a simple series of checks (max 5 digits, int of substring of convert to string and validate range should work.

Comment: Max of 5 digits or 5 digits? Also, that would mean your one example of `011569` would be wrong.

Comment: Write a separate expression for each possible first digit then "or" these all together. Your #3 is a bad example, it is 6 digits. What do you mean by max 5 digits if you allow leading zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Why regex? First you need a collection to store your ranges, for example:

```
Dim ranges = New List(Of Tuple(Of Int32, Int32))
ranges.Add(Tuple.Create(0, 16))
ranges.Add(Tuple.Create(20, 25))
ranges.Add(Tuple.Create(32, 39))
```

The check itself is pretty easy:

```
Dim firstTwo = text.TrimStart("0"c).Substring(0, 2)
Dim number As Int32
Dim isValid = Int32.TryParse(firstTwo, number) AndAlso 
              ranges.Any(Function(t) number >= t.Item1 AndAlso number <= t.Item2)
```